# Spinnaker Jfrog Artifactory Integration for Docker Registry

Tags: kubernetes, artifactory, spinnaker, amazon-eks, jfrog-container-registry

I'm trying to configure auto trigger on Spinnaker based on docker images pushed on Artifactory.

Artifactory and Spinnaker are running on same Elastic Kubernetes Cluster(EKS).
Artifactory address provided by LoadBalancer Service type is as - http://xxx.region.elb.amazonaws.com:80

Running below commands as per doc https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/docker-registry/#other-registries

```
hal config provider docker-registry enable


hal config provider docker-registry account add my-docker-registry --address http://xxx.region.elb.amazonaws.com:80 --repositories docker-local --username xxx --password xxx
```

It's throwing error as docker repository does not found.

```
  default.provider.dockerRegistry.my-docker-registry:
! ERROR Unable to fetch tags from the docker repository:
  docker-local, 404 Not Found
? Can the provided user access this repository?

- WARNING None of your supplied repositories contain any tags.
  Spinnaker will not be able to deploy any docker images.
? Push some images to your registry.

- Failed to add account my-docker-registry for provider
  dockerRegistry.
```

please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's resolved now, I had mistake in the command mentioning about repository

previous

```
hal config provider docker-registry account add my-docker-registry --address http://xxx.region.elb.amazonaws.com:80 --repositories docker-local --username xxx --password xxx
```

now

```
hal config provider docker-registry account add my-docker-registry --address http://xxx.region.elb.amazonaws.com:80 --repositories docker-local/nodejs-basic --username xxx --password xxx
```